# how to change position sidenav materialize using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I want to making a checkbox for change position in sidenav materialize using jquery, but this doesn't seem to work. This is my JS code:

```
 $('#toggle-side-nav-position').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){

    console.log('left');

    $('.side-nav-settings-toggle').sideNav({
      edge: 'left'
    });

  } else {

    console.log('right');

    $(".side-nav-settings-toggle").sideNav({
      edge: 'right'
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: I got this, works for the first click and then the object creates again and appears in the middle of everything.

$(".button-collapse").sideNav({
      edge: this.sidebarPositionValue
    });